# What are the benefits and limitations of Apriori algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, pattern-recognition, unsupervised-learning, apriori

1. In which scenarios will Apriori algorithm fail?
2. Is A->B & B->A considered the same in Apriori? Do they have same support, confidence & Lift?

Answer (score 2):

1. It is exact. It computes the frequent itemset exactly. It may of course run out of memory, or time.
2. No, rules are *not symmetric* unless P(A)=P(B)

Answer (score 1):

1) When the size of the database is very large, the Apriori algorithm will fail. because large database will not fit with memory(RAM). So each pass requires large number of disk reads.

**ex:** 1GB database stored in hard disk with block size 8KB require roughly 125,000 block reads for a single pass. for 10 passes require roughly 1,250,000 block reads. Assume it takes 12 ms to read a single block. That means it take roughly 3.5 hrs time for entire block reads.

Solution to this problem is the Partition algorithm. **Partition algorithm** accomplishes the task in two scans of the database.

i) Generate a set of potentially large item sets by scanning the database once.

- divides the database into a number of non-overlapping partitions
- partitions are considered one at a time
- all large itemsets for each partition are generated
- these large itemsets form candidate itemsets for Database

ii) The actual supports of these itemsets are measured in the next scan

- the actual support for these itemsets are generated
- the large itemsets are identified

The partition sizes are chosen such that each partition
can be accommodated in the main memory

**NOTE:**

- Any frequent item set with respect to a partition may or may not be
  frequent with respect to the entire Database D
- All local frequent item sets are candidate item sets with respect to D
- Any item set that is frequent with respect to D must occur as a
  frequent itemset in at least one of the partitions

2).
**RULE: A->B**

A->B indicate that if a customer buys item A , then they are likely to buy Item B.

**RULE B->A**

B->A indicate that if a customer buys item B, then they are likely to buy 
Item A

So those are not same.

**support**: is an indication of how frequently the item set appear in the database.

```
support of (A->B)= P(A∩B)
support of (B->A)= P(A∩B)
```

since P(A∩B)=P(A∩B) , support of (A->B) should equal with support of (B->A)

**confidence**: is an indication of how often the rule has been found to be true.

```
confidence of (A->B) = P(A∩B)/p(A)
confidence of (B->A) = P(A∩B)/p(B)
```

Since P(A∩B)/p(A) != P(A∩B)/p(B), confidence values are not equal.

**Lift**: is an indication of correlation measure between two items.

```
lift(A,B)= P(A∪B)/P(A)P(B)
lift(B,A)= P(B∪A)/P(B)P(A)
```

since P(A∪B)/P(A)P(B)=P(B∪A)/P(B)P(A), lift values are equals.

lift(A,B) <1, negatively correlated

lift(A,B) >1, positively correlated

lift(A,B) =1, no correlation

Answer (score 0):

1. I think the algorithm will always work, but the problem is the efficiency of using this algorithm.
2. If A->B and B->A are the same in Apriori, the support, confidence and Lift should be the same. Hence, If you evaluate the results in Apriori, you should do some test like Jaccard, consine, Allconf, Maxconf, Kulczynski and Imbalance ratio.

Hopefully, the above can help you .

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm works well and will not cause any issue just because it considers A->B and B->A as same because this is an approach used for cross-selling the products based on the market based analysis. The primary limitation of this alogirithm is the efficiency, as mentioned above. Apriori algorithm may become really slow especially when there are more candidates to analyze.